# How to leave a GitLab project not owned by me as Maintainer 2022?

Tags: gitlab

I searched and tried some ways to Leave a group, but here is the problem.
When I go to **Groups/Members** I can see myself, but I can't **Leave**.
For other groups there was a **Leave button**, so I left, but in other projects there is no **Leave button** to click.

So, the question will be How to **Leave without Leave button** from a group not owned by me ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you a member of the group (or ancestor group) that contains the project?

Answer (score 1):

Under the following conditions, you won't be able to "leave" a project in the members tab:

1. You are the sole maintainer/owner (in which case, add another user to remove yourself)
2. You are a member of the group (or an ancestor group) that contains the project (in which case, you need to manage your membership on the appropriate group level)
3. The project is in your personal namespace (e.g. `user.name/myproject`)
4. Your access is granted through a [share](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/share_project_with_groups.html), in which case, you need to manage this on the share tab.